# plot coefficients of a model in R

Tags: r

I am fitting training data with `glm()` and want to plot the coefficients. however, I had no clue how to give a right plot as follows:

[image]

```
set.seed(1)
trn_index = createDataPartition(y = development$EQUAL_PAY, p = 0.80, list = FALSE)
trn_pay = development[trn_index, ]
tst_pay = development[-trn_index, ]

trn_pay_f <- trn_pay %>%
  mutate(EQUAL_PAY = relevel(factor(EQUAL_PAY),ref = "YES"))

pay_lgr = train(EQUAL_PAY ~ .- EQUAL_WORK - COUNTRY, method = "glm", family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = trn_pay_f,trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10))

summary(pay_lgr)
##Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                -2.560e+00  2.552e+00  -1.003   0.3158  
GDP_PER_CAP                -5.253e-05  3.348e-05  -1.569   0.1167  
CO2_PER_CAP                 1.695e-01  7.882e-02   2.151   0.0315 *
PERC_ACCESS_ELECTRICITY    -7.833e-03  1.249e-02  -0.627   0.5304  
ATMS_PER_1E5               -2.473e-03  8.012e-03  -0.309   0.7576  
PERC_INTERNET_USERS        -2.451e-02  2.047e-02  -1.198   0.2310  
SCIENTIFIC_ARTICLES_PER_YR  2.698e-05  1.519e-05   1.776   0.0757 .
PERC_FEMALE_SECONDARY_EDU   1.126e-01  5.934e-02   1.897   0.0578 .
PERC_FEMALE_LABOR_FORCE    -6.559e-03  1.477e-02  -0.444   0.6569  
PERC_FEMALE_PARLIAMENT     -4.786e-02  2.191e-02  -2.184   0.0289 *

## extract all parameters in a dataframe
pay_lgrFrame <- data.frame(COEFFICIENT = rownames(summary(pay_lgr)$coef),
p_value = summary(pay_lgr)$coef[,4],
z_value = summary(pay_lgr)$coef[,3],
SE = summary(pay_lgr)$coef[,2],
Estimate = summary(pay_lgr)$coef[,1])

## and I was stuck in making a plot as the image I posted the link above.
```

Comment: Please add images using the browse option or paste in your question. Links may disappear in the future and/or some people may not have access to the link.

Comment: You'll likely need to use `acast` but not sure.

Comment: https://www.r-statistics.com/2010/07/visualization-of-regression-coefficients-in-r/

Comment: Agree with Chase. Using barplots as illustrated in your request is an inferior method of displying coefficients and standard errors. The modified doplot method in his suggested link is superior.

Comment: These resources might be helpful: [`dotwhisker` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotwhisker/vignettes/dotwhisker-vignette.html), [`summ` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/summ.html), [`coefplot` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coefplot/index.html).

Comment: Thank you all your replies and I initially searched your suggestions already. But this is the part of my homework, so we need to give a plot exactly same as that image.

Comment: Check out `geom_bar` or `geom_col` from the `ggplot2` package.

Answer (score 2):

Pulling in your summary table (you can get this directly as `ss <- coef(summary(pay_lgr))`, but I don't have your data set):

```
ss <- read.delim(header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,text="
Estimate    Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -2.560e+00  2.552e+00   -1.003  0.3158
GDP_PER_CAP -5.253e-05  3.348e-05   -1.569  0.1167
CO2_PER_CAP 1.695e-01   7.882e-02   2.151   0.0315
PERC_ACCESS_ELECTRICITY -7.833e-03  1.249e-02   -0.627  0.5304
ATMS_PER_1E5    -2.473e-03  8.012e-03   -0.309  0.7576
PERC_INTERNET_USERS -2.451e-02  2.047e-02   -1.198  0.2310
SCIENTIFIC_ARTICLES_PER_YR  2.698e-05   1.519e-05   1.776   0.0757
PERC_FEMALE_SECONDARY_EDU   1.126e-01   5.934e-02   1.897   0.0578
PERC_FEMALE_LABOR_FORCE -6.559e-03  1.477e-02   -0.444  0.6569
PERC_FEMALE_PARLIAMENT  -4.786e-02  2.191e-02   -2.184  0.0289")
```

Convert row names to a column called `term`:

```
ss2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(ss,"term")
```

Draw the barplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ss2, aes(term,Estimate))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      coord_flip()
ggsave("bar.png")
```

[image]

As others have commented, there are probably better (both easier and preferable in terms of visual communication) ways to plot the coefficients. The `dotwhisker::dwplot()` function does several convenient things:

- automatically extracts coefficients and plots them
- automatically scales continuous predictors by 2*std dev, to enable comparison between coeficients (use `by_2sd=FALSE` if you don't want this)
- automatically leaves out the intercept, which is on a different scale from the other parameters and is rarely of inferential interest

```
library(dotwhisker)
dwplot(lm(Murder/Population ~ ., data=as.data.frame(state.x77)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, I think my coefficients might be wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  It's not clear to me what "my coefficients might be wrong" means - if you have a problem with your model that's a separate issue, right? (If you're using `dotwhisker::dwplot()`,  please double-check the points that I stated about automatic scaling)

Comment: Thank you Ben, it is about a scaling issue. I have to use preProcess = c("center", "scale") within train()

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  I've answered the question you posted to the best of my ability. If you edit your question I (or someone else) might try to answer it, or you can ask another question